# Link para editar outra janela aberta

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Seguinte, tenho uma página que, ao clicar em um botão, abre uma nova janela.
Nesta nova página eu gostaria de colocar links que afetassem a página que gerou essa janela.

Alguém sabe como fazer?

Comment: eu tenho a janela A, que ao clicar no botão, ele gera um relatorio em uma janela nova. os links desse relatorio (janela nova) devem afetar a janela A.

Comment: Sabe usar a classe `window` do javascript?

Comment: nunca usei. tem alguns exemplos

Answer (score 1):

Caso a aba for no mesmo domínio você pode acessar a página pai que abriu através do [`window.opener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.opener). Se for domínios diferentes vai te proibir de acessar o `document` na maioria dos navegadores.

```
function alteraPaginaPai() {
    window.opener.document.getElementById('lbl').innerHTML = "Alteração!!"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nos dois artigos abaixo listados você vai ver como pode detalhadamente explorar as propriedades do objeto `window` em *JavaScript*

[**Explorando as propriedades do objeto window em JavaScript**](http://www.devmedia.com.br/explorando-as-propriedades-do-objeto-window-em-javascript/27254)

[**Operações avançadas com popups em Javascript**](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3483/operacoes-avancadas-com-popups-em-javascript.aspx)

Como um breve exemplo, você pode utiliar dentro do `pop-up` ou `iframe` o `window.parent` para conseguir acessar variáveis e funções da janela principal do browser.

Answer (score -1):

Na opção target tens as opçoes:
_blank 
_parent 
_self 
_top 
framename

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_parent">Visit google.com!</a>
```

e a que tu queres é parent.
espero ter ajudado.
cumpz

Comment: não é bem isso que eu queria. eu tenho a janela A, que ao clicar no botão, ele gera um relatorio em uma janela nova. os links desse relatorio (janela nova) devem afetar a janela A.

Comment: eu acho que isso não dá. o que voce pode fazer é utilizar sempre na mesma pagina. janela A abre link -> janela B. na janela B abre link para a janela A... não estou a ver outra maneira. espero ter ajudado. pode ser que alguem saiba outra maneira! ;)

Comment: @LPSANTOS ele está citando *javascript* como uma das *tags* da pergunta, sendo assim é necessário avaliar a possibilidade dentro desta linguagem também. No javascript eu posso controlar iframes e pop-ups utilizando a classe `window`. Já perguntei se ele sabe utilizar, caso ele responda negativamente vou mostrar pra ele alguns exemplos de como utilizar para manipular janelas com esta classe.

Comment: ola @Erlon Charles, tem razão, eu nem reparei na tag do javascript, pois assim talvez seja possivel!, eu não trabalho muito com javaScript. mas obrigado pela dica!